# EBS as Image Storing

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-ebs, amazon-efs

In my scenario CDN request are for images on the article pages, I want to make sure that they exist before rendering, if one doesn't exist we show a generic one An example is https://cloudfront.abc.com/CDNSource/teasers/56628.jpg there is 1 image per article.

The problem is occurs when The synchronous requests held the page execution for many minutes and then the load balancer timed out the request. looks like caused by making HTTP requests with no HTTP timeout.

Currently, my resources are in S3 so perhaps a CRON that syncs data hourly to the webservers, and the webservers take a copy of the S3 bucket when building. I think For that solution though I'd need an EBS to scale to our total image size. I'm not sure about it. Can anyone please guide me on how to calculate it, what that would be?

I had tried to use EFS for session storage previously but found its cost was far too high for us to use in production, +$15,000/mo. also please advise if there would be a better solution for this?

Comment: No idea what the title has to do with the body. Use e.g. AWS lambda to scale the images, there are tons of tutorials for that.

Comment: The simplest architecture is that all images should be served from S3. You could use Lambda @ Edge to capture situations where files don't exist. Take a look at [Resizing Images with Amazon CloudFront & Lambda@Edge | AWS CDN Blog | Networking & Content Delivery](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/resizing-images-with-amazon-cloudfront-lambdaedge-aws-cdn-blog/), but modify it to return a default image rather than resizing an image.

Comment: Thanx John, can I go with the idea that an EBS to scale to our total image size. Could you please guide me how calculate it & what that would be?
Ideally a local file resource would be available to check if something does/doesn't exist. Could you also please advise if there would be a better solution for this?